Remove vertical line between two cells in a LaTeX longtable
I use this code in LaTeX to make a table:
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{0.08\linewidth}|p{0.08\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Text O}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Text S}}\\
    &&\\
    \cline{2-3}
    &P&P\\ \hline
    1&2&3\\ \hline
    4&5&6\\ \hline
 \end{longtable}
 \end{center}


How do I erase the vertical line between column 2 and 3 (vertical line in Text S cell)?
Thank you :)

Welcome to TeX.SE.

With this example, you would want to reduce O's multirow to 2, and remove the multirow for S.  Does your actual example have more text to S so that it needs the 2x2 cells?

One way to fix the formatting is to replace the line
&&\\

with
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\

i.e., to replace the second & symbol with \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}.

A full minimum working example of MWE, which also (a) gets rid of the unnecessary and counterproductive center wrapper and (b) uses \endhead and \endlastfoot directives to provide some structure to the longtable material:

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | c | *{2}{p{0.08\linewidth}|} }

% table header
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Text O}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Text S}} \\
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-3}
      & P & P \\ \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \endlastfoot
      
% body of table

    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}

